# Simple_Form and Bootstrap 3 Form Validation Notification Stopped Working

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap, simple-form

I'm still learning RoR and have followed various tutorials online. In that process I believe I have messed up the nice flash notifications that Bootstrap 2 showed when validating Simple_Form submissions. I have tried to update my code, but without success. Here is what I have so far...

Running:
Rails 3.2.13
Ruby 2.0.0

I just upgraded to Bootstrap 3 using this gem in my **gemfile**:

```
gem 'bootstrap-sass-rails'
```

In my **application.html.erb** I have:

```
<%= render 'layouts/messages' %>
```

In my **_messages** partial I have:

```
<% flash.each do |type, message| %>
  <div class="alert <%= bootstrap_class_for(type) %> fade in">
    <button class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button>
    <%= message %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

In my **application_helper.rb** I have:

```
def bootstrap_class_for flash_type
    case flash_type
      when :success
        "alert-success"
      when :error
        "alert-error"
      when :alert
        "alert-block"
      when :notice
        "alert-info"
      else
        flash_type.to_s
    end
  end
```

In my **users_controller.rb** I have:

```
def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'Account successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

And in my **edit.html.erb** view I have:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@user) do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :firstname %>
    <%= f.input :lastname %>
    <%= f.input :email %>
    <%= f.input :password %>
    <%= f.input :password_confirmation %>
    <%= f.submit "Save changes", class: "btn btn-lg btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

The validation works, but when returned to the edit view, no formatting (red for errors) or flash message appears. Only a very hard to spot message outside each field is displayed. I must be missing some link between Simple_Form and Bootstrap 3, just don't know what.

I found another post where poster suggested to add:

```
config.input_class = "form-control"
```

to my simple_form initializer, but that gave me an error (think I might not have the latest version?):

```
undefined method `input_class=' for SimpleForm:Module (NoMethodError)
```

I wish I knew what was going on but I really hope someone can help me get the formatting and flash messages back. Apologies if this is a total newbie question, but I feel a little lost and possibly regretting that I upgraded too soon to Bootstrap 3 maybe.

A thousand thanks in advance to anyone reading all this :)

Comment: When you inspect the code in the browser, is the HTML for the flash message there?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I got flash to work with the help from @prodigerati comment. I'm still trying to figure out how to get the formatting of my simple_form elements (used to show up in red text and red outlined form field).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got the following mix of code from [railscasts.com](http://www.railscasts.com) and other websites.

```
<% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
<div class="alert alert-<%= name == :notice ? "success" : "error" %>">
   <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</a>
      <%= msg %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Add this to the top of your controller:

```
respond_to :html, :json
```

Put this in each controller action:

```
def create
  ...
  flash[:notice] = 'User was successfully created.'
  respond_with(@user)
end
```

works with rails 3.2+ and 4.0 and twitter bootstrap rails 2, untested in tbsr 3 but will probably work fine.

Comment: Thanks this actually got my flash messages working! I changed the <div class="alert alert-<%= name == :notice ? "success" : "error" %>"> to just <div class="alert alert-<%= name %>"> so I can use the other bootstrap alerts. Now I have to change all my redirect_to url, notice: to set the flash before redirect. I'm still trying to figure out why my simple_form elements are not colored after upgrading to TBS3, but will accept this as an answer if I don't get an answer about that :)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me far much better than others as it;s shorter and includes all alert cases -> *error, success, alert & notice* provided by Bootstrap.

N.B: I renamed your _messages partial to _flash_messages because that is what most people use.

And for those who may be wondering where to generate the _flash_messages partial, it's pretty easy, just right-click your *layouts* folder in *views* and 'add new file'. You can call it _flash_messages as I've done, and ensure you have that first underscore (_) before 'flash...'. Tap 'Save'

Now in your *_flash_messages.html.erb* partial, use this

```
    <% unless flash.blank? %>
       <% flash.each do |type, message| %>
          <div class="alert <%= flash_class(type.to_s) %>">
             <button class="close" data-dismiss="alert">x</button>
          <%= message %>
          </div>
       <% end %>
    <% end %>
```

And in your *application_helper.rb* use this

```
       def flash_class (type)
          case type
             when 'error'
                 "alert-error"
             when 'notice'
                 "alert-info"
             when 'alert'
                 "alert-block"
             when 'success'
                 "alert-success
          else
             type.to_s
          end
     end
```

Then in your *application.html.erb*, add this as your first line in your first div

```
<%= render partial: 'layouts/flash_messages', flash: flash %>
```

Notice that we render the partial (any partial that is), without the 'starter' underscore(_), i.e before the word 'flash..'

You can check out this answer from [teamtreehouse](https://teamtreehouse.com/community/cant-get-the-flash-messages-loop-to-display-different-alert-classes) on displaying different alert cases.

Hope this helps!